# How do I change the font colour of text in the same line in HTML5 without using div tags and WITHOUT CONTAINERS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

In HTML4, it used to be just

```html
<html>
<body>
<font color="tomato">ABC</font>&nbsp<font color ="blue">Airlines</font>
</body>
</html>
```

But apparently, it's non-functional in html5. In the w3schools tutorial, it says that we should use -

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<p style="color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

but I can't change the font individually of 2 words in the same line. What do I do? I don't want to use div for this.

Comment: Since it looks like a logo and known text-length, background-clip can be used : example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGBrXpW (Also added a stroke and a shadow from a single tag)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the <span> tags.

```html
<html>
<p>
  <span style="color: red">ABC</span>
  &nbsp
  <span style="color: blue">Airlines</span>
</p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use span tag for individual styling
You can style whatever you want like font, color so on...

Like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<p >
  <span style="color:red"> This is </span>
  <span style="color:green"> Paragraph </span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```